# What's wrong with Qt for Python base project?

Tags: python, qt, pyside2

I'm trying to load a .ui file in pyside2, but the basic scaffolding made by Qt Creator won't load my MainWindow.

```
# This Python file uses the following encoding: utf-8
import sys
import os


from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PySide2.QtCore import QFile
from PySide2.QtUiTools import QUiLoader


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.load_ui()

    def load_ui(self):
        loader = QUiLoader()
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "mainwindow.ui")
        ui_file = QFile(path)
        ui_file.open(QFile.ReadOnly)
        loader.load(ui_file, self)
        ui_file.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    widget = MainWindow()
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This is prepared by Qt Creator, but I can't get it to work.
The only way I've found to open my .ui file is by using this code, which does almost the same thing, except subclassing QMainWindow.

This other simple code works, but I can't understand why

````
import sys
import os


from PySide2.QtUiTools import QUiLoader
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PySide2.QtCore import QFile, QIODevice

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

     ui_file_name = "mainwindow.ui"
     path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), ui_file_name)
     ui_file = QFile(path)
#    ui_file = QFile(ui_file_name)
     if not ui_file.open(QIODevice.ReadOnly):
         print("Cannot open {}: {}".format(ui_file_name, ui_file.errorString()))
         sys.exit(-1)
     loader = QUiLoader()
     window = loader.load(ui_file)
     ui_file.close()
     if not window:
         print(loader.errorString())
         sys.exit(-1)
     window.show()

     sys.exit(app.exec_())```
````